# Jquery call .load function success but immediately fresh back

Tags: jquery

I have a simple JQuery

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("#button_overview").on("click", function(){   $("#homepagecontent").load("../description/overview.htm");   });

});
</script>
```

By clicking the button, htm is loaded for 1 sec and than the page fresh back to previous stage. Looks like entire page is refreshed. Am I missing something in script?

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove JavaScript immediate function invoke $(function() {});

```
<script>

$("#button_overview").on("click", function(){   $("#homepagecontent").load("../description/overview.htm");   });

</script>
```